# Office 365 Powerpoint add-in problem with opening

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office365, powerpoint, office-addins

I am trying to create Office 365 Powerpoint Add-in. I am using Yeoman generator. I start with:

```
yo office
```

and then I choose following settings:

```
Office Add-in Task Pane project using React framework - for project type
Typescript - for typescript or javascript
PowerPointAddIn - for project name
Powerpoint - for application
```

then I switch to project folder and do:

```
npm instal
```

and then:

```
npm start
```

As a result I get following:

```
Debugging is being started...
App type: desktop
Enabled debugging for add-in 05c2e1c9-3e1d-406e-9a91-e9ac64854143.
The dev server is already running on port 3000.
Sideloading the Office Add-in...
Error: Unable to start debugging.
office-addin-debugging: Unable to sideload the Office Add-in.
office-addin-dev-settings: The Office Add-in manifest does not support Excel.
```

and nothing gets started, even if I close dev server and try again. I want to mention that if I do create add-in for Word, or Excel, with same methodology, everything works as expected. What could be wrong? It is suspicious that it mentions Excel, although I didn't create add-in for Excel. Host in manifest file is ok:

```
<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Presentation"/>
</Hosts>
```